# Combine two ArrayList of object and conditionally change value of object while combining

Tags: java, arraylist

I want to combine two arraylist of similar type. But conditionally, if property of one object match, property of other object than combine them in one.

Here is my model class

```
public class SampleModel {

    int number;
    String name;
    boolean isSimilar;

    public SampleModel(int number, String name, boolean isSimilar) {
        this.number = number;
        this.name = name;
        this.isSimilar = isSimilar;
    }

    public int getNumber() {
        return number;
    }

    public void setNumber(int number) {
        this.number = number;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public boolean isSimilar() {
        return isSimilar;
    }

    public void setSimilar(boolean similar) {
        isSimilar = similar;
    }


    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        boolean result = false;
        if (this == o){
            result = true;
        }
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()){
            result = false;
        }
        SampleModel that = (SampleModel) o;

        if(name.matches("(.*)"+that.name+"(.*)")){
            result = true;
        }

        if(name.matches("(.*)"+that.name)){
            result = true;
        }

        if(name.matches(that.name+"(.*)")){
            result = true;
        }

        if(name.contains(that.name)){
            result= true;
        }

        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(name);
    }
}
```

And I have two arrylist of this type of object Like this

```
    ArrayList<SampleModel> sampleModels_one = new ArrayList<SampleModel>();
    ArrayList<SampleModel> sampleModels_two = new ArrayList<SampleModel>();
    ArrayList<SampleModel> combined = new ArrayList<SampleModel>();

    sampleModels_one.add(new SampleModel(1,"a",true));
    sampleModels_one.add(new SampleModel(1,"b",true));
    sampleModels_one.add(new SampleModel(1,"c",true));

    sampleModels_two.add(new SampleModel(1,"b",false));
    sampleModels_two.add(new SampleModel(2,"c",false));
    sampleModels_two.add(new SampleModel(3,"d",false));
    sampleModels_two.add(new SampleModel(3,"e",false));
```

I want to combine them in such way, so the output of `combined` will be like this

```
SampleModel(1,"a",true)
SampleModel(1,"b",true)
SampleModel(1,"c",true)
SampleModel(1,"d",false)
SampleModel(1,"e",false)
```

I have looked other SO question but couldn't find a efficient way to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with Set like this.(can use linkedhashset for maintaining order)

```
        combined.addAll(sampleModels_two);
        combined.addAll(sampleModels_one);

        Set<SampleModel> hs = new LinkedHashSet<>();
        hs.addAll(sampleModels_one);
        hs.addAll(sampleModels_two);
        combined.clear();
        combined.addAll(hs);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't care about the ordering of the elements, it might make more sense to use a `Set` instead.
If you add elements to a `Set` then the elements are tested with `.equals` and duplicates are not added.

However if you need to have some sense of ordering to your list then you can use the [`removeAll(Collection<?> c)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#removeAll(java.util.Collection)) method to remove duplicate elements of the list.

Like this ...

`ArrayList<SampleModel> combined = new ArrayList<SampleModel>();
combined.addAll(sampleModels_one);
combined.removeAll(sampleModels_two);
combined.addAll(sampleModels_two);`